# Writing to SQLite tables with variable names (Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dataframe

I'm trying to write five variables to tables in a database using SQLite and Python. Below is my code and the error I'm getting:

**CODE:**

```
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + " (Date real, Morning_5AM_9AM real, Day_9AM_6PM real, Evening_6PM_10PM real, Night_10PM_5AM real)")   # this works
        export_row= p_transpose.iloc[ii]                 # Note: p_transpose is the transpose of a DataFrame I read in from Excel
        date_object= p_transpose.iloc[ii,0]              # date_object is a string here
        date_object= date_object.replace('_','')
        export_date= int(date_object)                    # to insert into database table as int instead of string 
        export_morning= p_transpose.iloc[ii,1]
        export_day= p_transpose.iloc[ii,2]
        export_eve= p_transpose.iloc[ii,3]
        export_night= p_transpose.iloc[ii,4]
        cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
        available_tables=[item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]         # assigns a list of all table names in database
        for iii in range (0, row_count): 
            if (re.match('\w*'+df_feeder, available_tables[iii])):
                relevant_table= available_tables[iii]
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + relevant_table + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" (export_date, export_morning, export_day, export_eve, export_night))
```

**ERROR on the last line:**

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I've made sure that none of the `export_...` variables contain strings, so the string must be `relevant_table`. However, *creating* a table using a string variable (see code above again) worked fine so I don't understand why it's giving this error now.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if any additional information would be useful.

**EDIT**:

Here is my traceback, gotten using traceback.format_exc():

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/run.py"‌​, line 112, in main\n seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)\n File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 176, in get\n raise Empty\nEmpty\n'
```

**FINAL EDIT, RESOLVED:**

For information, thanks to scytale, this now works, using:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + relevant_table + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (export_date, export_morning, export_day, export_eve, export_night))
```

I thought I had tried changing the punctuation and spacing  in all ways possible, but this finally did the trick.

Comment: please show more of the stacktrace - you have omitted the part that tells us what line in your code caused the error

Comment: Sure - I have made edits based on your comment and added some detail. As mentioned, the error is caused by the last line of the code. Is there anything specific you'd like to know beyond this?

Comment: please add more of the stacktrace - it's just good practice - putting a comment in your code is not nearly as good

Comment: by stacktrace do you mean output?

Comment: google "python stacktrace"

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/run.py", line 112, in main\n    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)\n  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 176, in get\n    raise Empty\nEmpty\n'

Comment: that's completely illegible. please edit your quesiton to add the stacktrace there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a comma in your last line after the SQL string - it should be

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + relevant_table + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
            (export_date, export_morning, export_day, export_eve, export_night))
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:
OperationalError: near "?": syntax error. 

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: also - you need to add a space before `VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

Really, for clarity and future maintenance you should be specific as to what and where you are inserting. So your statement should read something like this, for example:

```
    try:
        result = self.db.execute("insert into Recent (Filename,TimeStamp,Icon) values (?,?,?)",(filename,time_stamp,itype))
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        wx.MessageBox('Insert Recent file list error'+str(e), 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

This makes it clear, not only what the data items are but where you are putting them.
A good reason for declaring what you are inserting explicitly, is that should you add columns to the table at a later date, then the code will still work as expected.

As a side note, has everyone forgotten the power of the print statement when it comes to debugging?
Got a problem? PRINT the damned stuff out and look at it!! 9 times out of ten it's obvious.

Comment: Rolf, I've used the print statement plenty along the way - I just deleted those lines in my code when pasting here to make it shorter. I don't really understand the last two lines of the code you wrote, could you explain this a little more? And I apologize if you thought what I was inserting was unclear, I tried to read over my question a few times to make sure it was not.

Comment: @LinnK. Glad to hear that "print" hasn't been deserted for stacktraces and fancy debuggers. The last 2 lines are nothing more than the exception statement for the try, which will display a message box informing the user that the insert into the database failed. I'm hoping here, that those are the two lines that you are referring to. I didn't mention in my answer that one good reason for declaring what you are inserting explicitly, is that should you add columns to the table at a later date, then the code will still work as expected.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, that's good advice. I'll work that into my code as well. And thank you for the explanation, I'm quite new to programming in Python as maybe you can tell.